# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

Tags: java, ssl, curl

Encountered this SSLException when using curl to hit a Java web service:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1225) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:913) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

cURL output:

```
[team@pins ~]$ curl -v --data '' 'https://example.com:6521/access/register'
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f857480bb00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f857480bb00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to example.com port 6521 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to example.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 6521 (#0)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to example.com:-9800
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to example.com:-9800
```

Strangely, the same command works on another machine with an older version of cURL. There, it appears to be working fine with AES128-SHA.

I suspect it's a problem with the available ciphers sent during ssl negotiation, but I'm unsure how to debug that. Is there a way to see exactly what cURL sent? Or exactly what the server received?

Comment: Nonagreement on cipher(s) would go the other direction: handshake_failure from Java server to (curl) client. Is your curl build using openssl? If so and maybe even if not, try `openssl s_client -connect host:port -state` and if that isn't specific enough add `-msg` or `-debug`. (If openssl does connect, just signal EOF, usually ctrl-D or ctrl-Z, or enter upper-Q return.) Or get a network capture (wireshark is easiest to read IMO, and can import tcpdump/snoop/etc from Unix) or set sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` on the Java side (easy but more cluttered).